# Sending results of JMeter to a MySql DB

Tags: mysql, jmeter, grafana

I want to know if is possible to get a result csv of a JMeter test and send to a MySQL database, to be used on a Grafana Dashboard.

If it is possible, how can I do it without a GUI, in case I start running it on a Linux server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send results on the fly you can consider using [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener), the example code to establish a connection with MySQL database and insert the data would be something like:

```
def dburl = 'jdbc:mysql://your_mysql_host:your_mysql_port/your_database'
def user = 'mysql_username'
def password = 'mysql_password'
def driver = 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
groovy.sql.Sql.withInstance(dburl, user, password, driver) { sql ->
    def query = 'INSERT INTO metrics (samplerName, timeStamp, elapsed, latency, success) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'
    def params = [prev.getSampleLabel(), prev.getTimeStamp(), prev.getTime(), prev.getLatency(), prev.isSuccessful()]
    sql.executeInsert query, params
}
```

Where `prev` stands for the [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for all available metrics you might be interested in and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements.